# SOAP web service in JAX-RS REST service

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jax-ws

I'm considering moving a SOAP web service from using a JAX-WS implementation to a JAX-RS implementation, but keeping the request/response the same (XMLs that meet the SOAP protocol).  This would be to improve performance, have access to the streams, and use the NIO capabilities of Jersey 2/Servlet 3.1 to be able to do additional work after a response is sent back.  Is there any reason I should not do this?  Moving off of the SOAP protocol is not an option.  I am using WebLogic 12c and plan to use Jersey 2 with the prefer-application-packages setting.

The service itself acts as a SOAP client to another SOAP service.  I wanted to move that off of Spring WS to a REST client, because I didn't have any luck retrieving the response HTTP body content whenever it came as an HTML error page.  I want to have access to that data to be able to send that back to my client.  So same question as for the SOAP service itself, any issue with moving to a REST client or HTTP client?

Comment: You can do this if you are upto to the task of implementing your own xml deserializers and serializers which will meet the specs of soap message exchange format. otherwise, it will be too great a work.